# Visualize large and complex dataset

Tags: python, html, elasticsearch, kibana

How do I dynamically visualize large and complex data sets (stored in Elasticsearch) with dozens of sub-graphs and drill-downs? I would like some kind of dynamic control over this, but would prefer to not roll my own (in Python). Is it possible to use Kibana for this kind of thing? Or is there some better tool for the task?

Best would be if I could have rudimentary control over layout, then be able to show a number of bar charts if the user wants to see time series, but if she wants to slice it perpendicular I could show for instance pie charts. User should be able to interactively klick her way down, generating AND/OR lucene expressions, etc.

The more I rubber duck, the more I feel like I need to build this myself in Bokeh or something of the kind. If I need to create all such business logic manually, what would be my best HTML/graphing library? Or are there plugins for Kibana that does this perhaps? If I have to create things manually, it does not necessarily need to be in Python, but it needs to be back-end (for Elasticsearch security).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [my own](https://github.com/highfestiva/scimed-surveyor/tree/master/http-server), took around 500 LoC and a week or two of devopsing.